# How to make activity react to local Broadcasts while paused?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, broadcast

What is the best way to make an activity (if there is any) react to a broadcast that was send over a [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) while the activity was paused or stopped. I couldn't find much details if the `LocalBroadcastManager` differs from a normal broadcast, but it seems that is still gets called event if the activity is in background. But that leads to some problems since some UI modifications are not possible as long as the activity is not shown.

That's why I would prefer to handle all broadcasts when the activity gets back to top. But how can I do this. I was thinking of a queue that will take a list of runnables that gets executed when the activity comes back to running state. But I think this is some sort of overkill since android surly does have a mechanism for that.

So whats the proper way to do this?

Comment: What is your purpose? I mean for example [content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and [loaders](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html) can be used to update UI efficiently. Maybe there are other ways to solve your problem?

Comment: I'm creating some X509 certificates in an AsyncTask and want to update my activity, when done.

Comment: The livecycle tag from this question should be removed. The tag is used for questions related to Adobe LiveCycle ES.

Answer (score 2):

What I've done in the past is have my activities register a receiver onResume and unregister onPause.

When you've finished creating your certificates save to local storage whatever information you need to update your view and send out the broadcast.

If the activity is running it will receive the broadcast and update itself. If it it is paused, you should read the local storage onResume and update accordingly.

Comment: I agree. And to Chris: using a service is better than an `AsyncTask` in this case, as the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) says: *… AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)*

Comment: @monkybonk05: That would be a possible way to do this but the way I use these certificates, I don't want them to be in persistant memory until a certain point in my application. Of course I could do it like you mentioned or as a static field. This even seems to be a common solution on android but I don't consider it to be clean code since it may lead to threading problems and redruces the flexibillity of my classes. The broadcast received by my activity is a local bit of code that should not depend on any modifications I have to do outside of this class. That's why I'm looking for another way.

Comment: @Chris If the app is in the background there is no guarantee it will return to the foreground. It is possible for it to be removed from memory if the OS needs resources. That being said, I would recommend you re-evaluating when it's safe to persist your data

Answer (score 1):

After all I found a solution that fits my needs. I create a BroadcastReceiver that is used as a subclass of my activity. Whenever the activity enters a paused state, it will call .pause() on my BroadcastReceiver. From that point all incoming Intents are put into a queue and will be flushed on a call to .unpause() from the activity.

Comment: Where do you register the receiver? Is the queuing system already included in `BroadcastReceiver` or did you have to implement it yourself?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you simply unregister the receiver onDestroy? So while activity is paused, you can still execute code in the receiver?

Comment: Per the Android docs, this method is not guaranteed to be called, and you could get a Leaked Broadcast Receiver exception when the activity is restarted. If you are targeting SDK versions after Honeycomb, you can unregister the receiver in onStop(). If you are targeting pre-Honeycomb devices, then onStop might not be called as well.