# update adapter data while activity is paused

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i have an adapter in activity and its  arrayList

```
private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

and i have brodcastReciver too when i get data i add it to the ArrayList data

```
data.add("bla bla bla"); // brodcast data
```

and update adapter

but my adapter not updated when activity its paused and i missed the brodcast data

so what the solution for this i just made some search and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16151020/8837120) but he did't share the idea

my app idea its chatting app with sqlite of Course and the problem i missed the BrodcastEvent when activity its paused and get the data from sqlite every time activity its resumed i see it as bad idea

Answer (score 0):

The `BroadcastReceiver` would receive event without activity start or resume If register it in your manifest.

```
<receiver android:name="YourReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.YourAction" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Another issue, how `BroadcastReceiver` notify message adapter.

You could define a singleton object as observer register manager. If `activity`  start, it register itself, and `BroadcastReceiver` notify it when receive new message.

`BroadcastReceiver`

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...
    SingletonRegister.getInstance().addMessage("bla bla bla");
}
```

`Activity`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    SingletonRegister.getInstance().observe(this);
}

@Override
public void update(String message) {            
    data.add(message);    
}
```

If `activity` don't start, `activity` would not get notified because of  not registered. In order to ensure receive all messages, `activity` need actively request last messages after register.

`Activity`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    SingletonRegister.getInstance().observe(this);
    requestMessageFromServer();
}
```